# Firefox cycles through Search engines endlessly

Tags: firefox

I have several search engines in my Firefox that I use regularly, eg. Wikipedia or Duckduckgo, Wiktionary and so on.

When I want to search anything with DuckDuckGo, I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, type in the word, hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> for a moment to cycle to the topmost entry without looking, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This does not work anymore, because Firefox now *cycles* through all the entries in the list, beginning at the other end if reaching one.

How can I get my old, better user experience back?